# What would be Google Maps data transfer limit?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, limit, data-transfer

Good morning

does anybody know what is the daily data transfer limit when we are not using an API key for **Google Maps** embedded in your website?

Thanks in advance

I saw google map api documentation and there is a property called :

`google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` -> indicates that you are over your quota.

When would I be over my quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V3 doesn't use keys and there is no limit on 'data'. There are limits on different services like directions, elevation and geocoding which vary. You can read the limits for each service on the docs http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html